# I can't set body background image in angular

Tags: css, angular, sass

If i put this code in the global css styles then it is working.The background image is set on the body of the page

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
  }

  body {
  background-image: url("../../assets/img/p.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  }
```

But if i try the same on some not global css style , for example of some copomnent then it is not working.I ve checked the path and it is correct.Also the styles are working for everything except for the body background image.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

you cannot do that because of [style encapsulation](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#view-encapsulation). whenever you style something inside component css Angular adds some dynamic attributes to that selectors, so for example

```
.some-class{
   color:red;
}
```

will transfer to (maybe)

```
   .some-class[ng-2312313]{
       color:red;
    }
```

and then this styles will be applied inside your component, by that Angular protects you from not styling some component from another component.

said that, styling body element inside a component will not work.
you can disable encapsulation, by viewEncapsulation property

```
@Component(.... encapsulation : ViewEncapsulation.NONE )
```

but doing so you will expose all your styles outside the component, so it's not best way to do it.
you could add these kinds of styles in global CSS (as you do now), it's the best way to do